# Use ssmtp in ubuntu when user clicks on mailto: html tag

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssmtp

I've set up an ubuntu machine with ssmtp.

My website has a mailto tag that is asking the browser how it wants to send the email, but I want it to be sent automatically using ssmtp settings without asking the user.

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=....">Testing</a>
```

How can I do this? Or should I use a PHP instruction for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible what I'm trying to do...

```
<a href="mailto:...">
```

is executed by the client and I want to use some server stuff instead.
If I'm not wrong, it will use some email app from the client, nothing from the server.

Comment: You are right, this is a purely client side configuration.

Comment: You can use a form instead of a mailto: link though.